# Does flutter video_player automatically use adaptive bitrate when using an HLS stream?

Tags: flutter, video, http-live-streaming, vimeo

I am using flutter video player to play an HLS stream from vimeo. As I understand it, HLS streams allow for adaptive bitrate based on connection quality.

What I am not sure, is if this behaviour is by default, and always in use, or does the player have to support adaptive bitrate. Specifically, does flutter video player use adaptive bitrate out of the gate with hls streams?

Thanks!